# Who is going to detect whether validators conduct misbehaviors?

Tags: proof-of-stake, validators, slashings

If validators act dishonestly, who is going to find that out?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, just one altruistic validator needs to detect and report misconduct by other validators.

For more information, see https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/incentives/slashing/#the-value-of-reporting-a-slashing

Answer (score 0):

In the Ethereum network, dishonest behavior by validators in the context of Ethereum 2.0 (Eth2) or proof-of-stake (PoS) consensus is subject to a mechanism called "slashing." Slashing is designed to penalize validators who perform malicious or undesirable actions, which is a significant deterrent for validators to act dishonestly because they stand to lose a portion of their staked assets.  Validators are economically incentivized to act honestly and in the best interests of the network.